# Problema con (.) en url amigables

Tags: regex, .htaccess, seo, pretty-urls

Tengo una web donde muestro un catálogo de productos, los cuales con las famosas url amigables, transforma dichas url.

Tengo:

```
www.miweb.com/productos/Plancha-para-ropa-nghkdk23
```

Y redirecciono a:

```
www.miweb.com/productos/productos.php?idproductos=302
```

Mi problema es cuando intento ver o seguir el link de un producto cuya descripcion tiene un punto (`.`). Ejemplo:

```
www.miweb.com/productos/Telefono-android-5.0
```

Siguiendo el link, me da una error, pero si hago esto (Reemplazo el `.` por un `-`) me funciona:

```
www.miweb.com/productos/Telefono-android-5-0
```

La cuestión es que no sé cómo modificar el .htaccess para que el signo punto (`.`) lo reemplace por un guión (`-`)

Aquí les dejo mi código actual:

```
RewriteRule ^prod/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ producto.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario reemplazarlo por un guión? ¿No es mejor aceptar el punto dentro del id?

Comment: Es muy necesario el guión

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien no está clara la redirección que se está realizando, ya que se muestra un ejemplo y luego se muestra una regla que no coincide con el ejemplo, la respuesta es sencilla.

**Para aceptar puntos en el ID:**

Hay que agregar el punto dentro de los caracteres permitidos:

```
RewriteRule ^prod/([-.A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-.A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ producto.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

---

**Para reemplazar los puntos por guiones:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^prod/([^./]*)\.(.*)$ /prod/$1-$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^prod/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ producto.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, justo lo que necesitaba